# parse method in xml throws IllegalArgumentException in Clojure

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, clojure

I'm following this [article](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/parsing_xml_with_zippers.html) for parsing XML in clojure. In the REPL, I enter the following things:

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])
(require '[clojure.xml :as xml])
(require '[clojure.zip :as zip])

(-> "example.nzb" io/resource io/file xml/parse zip/xml-zip)
```

I get a `IllegalArgumentException InputStream cannot be null  javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse (SAXParser.java)` on executing that. I figured out that the exception was being caused by `xml/parse` method:

```
(xml/parse (io/file (io/resource "example.nzb")))
```

Comment: Did you check that `(io/file (io/resource "example.nzb"))` is returning a non-nil value?

Comment: Don't use io/file in conjunction with io/resource - it won't work for JAR resources. Use io/input-stream instead. If that still returns nil, then you don't have a resource called "example.nzb" anywhere on your classpath.

Comment: @Alex `Using io/input-stream` raises this error: `IllegalArgumentException No implementation of method: :make-input-stream of protocol: #'clojure.java.io/IOFactory found for class: nil  clojure.core/-cache-protocol-fn (core_deftype.clj:541)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression mentioned in the question works. Just make sure that you have included the "example.nzb" file within your project and also make sure that you restart the REPL.